# Call private class method from private instance method

Tags: ruby, oop

I am new to Ruby and came from C# world. In C# it is legal to do stuff like this:

```
public class Test
{
  public void Method()
  {
     PrivateMethod();
  }

  private void PrivateMethod()
  {
     PrivateStaticMethod();
  }

  private static void PrivateStaticMethod()
  {
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do something similar in Ruby?

A little bit of context: I have a Rails app... One of the models has a private method that sets up some dependencies. There is a class method that creates initialized instance of the model. For legacy reasons there are some instances of the model that are not initialized correctly. I added an instance method that initializes 'uninitialized' instances where I want to do same initialization logic. Is there a way to avoid duplication?

Sample:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.create_instance
    model = MyModel.new
    model.init_some_dependencies # this fails
    model
  end

  def initialize_instance
    // do some other work
    other_init
    // call private method
    init_some_dependencies
  end

  private

  def init_some_dependencies
  end

end
```

I tried to convert my private method to a private class method, but I still get an error:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.create_instance
    model = MyModel.new
    MyModel.init_some_dependencies_class(model)
    model
  end

  def initialize_instance
    # do some other work
    other_init
    # call private method
    init_some_dependencies
  end

  private

  def init_some_dependencies
     MyModel.init_some_dependencies_class(self) # now this fails with exception
  end

  def self.init_some_dependencies_class(model)
    # do something with model
  end

  private_class_method :init_some_dependencies_class

end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let me try to explain why the code does not work

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.create_instance
    model = MyModel.new
    # in here, you are not inside of the instance scope, you are outside of the object
    # so calling model.somemething can only access public method of the object.
    model.init_some_dependencies
    ...
  end
  ...
```

You could bypass private calling of the method with `model.send :init_some_dependencies`. But I think in this case there is probably better solution.

I would guess that `init_some_dependencies` probably contain more business / domain logic rather than persistence. That's why I would suggest to pull out this logic into a "Domain Object" (or some call it Service Object). Which is just a plain ruby object that contain domain logic.

This way you could separate persistence logic to ActiveRecord and the domain logic to that class. Hence you will not bloat the ActiveRecord Model. And you get the bonus of testing
the domain logic without the need of ActiveRecord. This will make your test faster.

You could create a file say `lib/MyModelDomain.rb'

```
class MyModelDomain
  attr_accessor :my_model

  def initialize(my_model)
    @my_model = my_model    
  end

  def init_some_dependencies
    my_model.property = 'some value example' 
  end
end
```

Now you could use this object say something like this

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.create_instance
    model = MyModel.new
    domain = MyModelDomain.new(model)
    domain.init_some_dependencies
    domain.my_model
  end

  def initialize_instance
    # do some other work
    other_init

    domain = MyModelDomain.new(self)
    domain.init_some_dependencies
  end
end
```

You might also want to move the `initialize_instance` if you think it's necessary

Some resource that go deep into this pattern:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects
- https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/extracting-domain-objects

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
model = MyModel.new
model.send :init_some_dependencies
```

to bypass method visibility checks.

Answer (score -1):

> In C# it is legal to do stuff like this:
>
> ```
> public class Test
> {
>   public void Method()
>   {
>      PrivateMethod();
>   }
>
>   private void PrivateMethod()
>   {
>      PrivateStaticMethod();
>   }
>
>   private static void PrivateStaticMethod()
>   {
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Is it possible to do something similar in Ruby?

Yes:

```
class Test

  def method
    private_method()
  end


  def self.greet
    puts 'Hi'
  end

  private_class_method :greet


  private

  def private_method
    self.class.class_eval do
      greet
    end
  end

end

Test.new.method
Test.greet

--output:--
Hi
1.rb:23:in `<main>': private method `greet' called for Test:Class (NoMethodError)
```

But ruby doesn't strictly enforce privacy.  For instance,

```
class Dog
  def initialize
    @private = "secret password"
  end
end

puts Dog.new.instance_variable_get(:@private)

--output:--
secret password
```

ruby gives you the freedom to access private things with a little bit of extra effort:

```
Test.new.method

Test.class_eval do
  greet
end

--output:--
Hi
Hi
```

In ruby, a private method only means that you cannot explicitly specify a receiver for the method, i.e. there can't be a name and a dot to the left of the method. But in ruby, a method without a receiver implicitly uses self as the receiver.  So to call a private method, you just have to create a context where self is the correct receiver.  Both class_eval and instance_eval change self inside the block to *their* receiver, e.g.

```
some_obj.instance_eval do
  #Inside here, self=some_obj

  #Go crazy and call private methods defined in some_obj's class here

end
```

You can apply those rules to this situation:

```
(ahmy wrote:)

First let me try to explain why the code does not work

    class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

      def self.create_instance
        model = MyModel.new
        # in here, you are not inside of the instance scope, you are outside of the object
        # so calling model.somemething can only access public method of the object.
        model.init_some_dependencies  # this fails
        ...   end   ...
```

"Context this" and "scope that"--what a headache. All you have to remember is: you cannot call a private method with an explicit receiver. The method init_some_dependencies was defined as a private method--yet it has "model." written to the left of it.  That is an explicit receiver.  Bang!  An error.

Here is a solution:

```
class MyModel

  def self.create_instance
    #In here, self=MyModel
    puts self

    model = MyModel.new

    model.instance_eval do    #Changes self to model inside the block
      #In here, self=model
      init_some_dependencies  #Implicitly uses self as the receiver, so that line is equivalent to model.init_some_dependencies
    end

  end


  private

  def init_some_dependencies 
    puts "Dependencies have been initialized!"
  end
end

MyModel.create_instance

--output:--
MyModel
Dependencies have been initialized!
```

Or as ahmy and LBg pointed out, you can use Object#send() to call private methods:

```
class MyModel

  def self.create_instance
    model = MyModel.new
    model.send(:init_some_dependencies, 10, 20)
  end


  private

  def init_some_dependencies(*args)
    puts "Dependencies have been initialized with: #{args}!"
  end
end


MyModel.create_instance

--output:--
Dependencies have been initialized with: [10, 20]!
```

Comment: C# does not enforce privacy, you are able to access private in C# as well via reflection.

Comment: @Esailija, I don't know anything about C#.  It was a ruby question.

Answer (score -3):

acturally, it surely does.

Ruby's some OO strategies(`private` & `public` keywords etc.) comes from C++, so you can get almost same usage.

Comment: Let's see some documentation for that.

Comment: I didn't know matz could see the future! (Hint: Ruby came out almost a decade before C#.) Ruby's OO model is inspired by Smalltalk's, which is pretty as far away from both C++ and C# as possible.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I mean, what's important here is not what Ruby's Object Model from( of couse i know it's Smalltalk). Ruby is also get benifit from C++'s oo strategy such as `private` & `public` keywords.